# How to configure certificates for Grafana MQTT plugin to connect to HiveMQ cloud broker

Tags: ssl, mqtt, grafana, pem, hivemq

I'm running Grafana 9.3.6 installed via apt-get on Ubuntu 20.04.5

I have a HiveMQ cloud broker I'm trying to connect to.
Previously I succeeded to connect via mosquitto command line tool and mosquittopp C++ interface. These required me to provide a certificate or certificate path.

- I used the `.pem` file provided by HiveMQ with the command line tool.
- I provided the `/etc/ssl/certs/` path for the C++ interface (the 1st option did not work out)

Now I'm trying to connect via the Grafana MQTT plugin. I installed it using

`grafana-cli plugins install grafana-mqtt-datasource`.

When trying to add it in the web gui, I get the following error:

**`error connecting to MQTT broker: network Error : EOF`**

I can see some messages going back and forth in Wireshark so I assume the problem is with the certificates.

*I tried editing the `grafana.ini` file without success. It's not completely clear which file/path should I add where and what other options I need to set.*

Edit: the `grafana.ini` file had nothing to do with this.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75321603/edit) the question to give details of how you configured the plugin, what URL schema and port number did you supply? Also just to be clear, you are NOT using client side certificate authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @hardillb pointed out, I had to pay attention to the URL scheme. After putting `tls://` in front of the broker URL as described in [grafana-mqtt-datasource](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-mqtt-datasource/), everything worked.